# Printing RGB channels

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, rgb

If I have an RGB image i.e.: `img_RGB` and I print one of the channels. What is the difference exactly when doing `print(img_RGB[:,:,2])` or `print(img_RGB[:,:,1])`?
Because I tried it, and I obtained the same matrix. To my knowledge I am printing the values of the blue channel however I am not sure what difference it makes if I print the matrix when using either `'1'` or `'2'`

Image being used:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKIf4.jpg

Comment: What does `img_RGB[0,0]` return?

Comment: Python does not have a built-in image type. What data type is your `img_RGB`? If it's a numpy array, please at least tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @martineau Sorry, `img_RGB` is loading a .jpg image which was converted from GBR to RGB as shown:                                                                                                                     
`img = cv2.imread('WellPlate.jpg', -1)
img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta, as expected since the image is an RGB image, it returns [0 0 0]

Comment: @Jason well even though the format is RGB, from your question, it seemed like all the channels have same value. Hence whether you access by 1 or 2, there is no visible change. Now at the first pixel this hypothesis seems to be correct. Now you got to check whether all pixels are such. You can try something like: `(img_RGB == img_RGB.max(-1, keepdims=True)).all(-1).all()`, and check if it's True. If it is, then there is nothing wrong with your code, it is just that all the channels have same values.

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta I tried it and it returned False. However I do not understand how as you are stating that there is something wrong with my code because I am simply changing the color space of my image, not sure how exactly I could be doing any errors up till that stage.

Comment: I did not say there's anything wrong with your code, if all the channels had same value then there is no reason to doubt there could be anything wrong with your code. Anyhow, as you have provided the image, I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your image it seems most of the pixel have same value across all the channels (at least in `B` and `G`), that is why while printing you do not see the differences, because the number of different values are so few. We can inspect this in the following way:

```
>>> img = cv2.imread(fname, -1);img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
>>> img_RGB[:,:,2] == img_RGB[:,:,1]

array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Checking this result, one might be tempted to say that all are equal, however, if we look closely, that is not the case:

```
>>> (img_RGB[:,:,2] == img_RGB[:,:,1]).all()
False

# So there are some values that are not identical
# Let's get the indices

>>> np.nonzero(img_RGB[:,:,2] != img_RGB[:,:,1])
(array([  16,   16,   16, ..., 1350, 1350, 1350], dtype=int64),
 array([  83,   84,   85, ..., 1975, 1976, 1977], dtype=int64))

# So these are the indices, where :
# first element of tuple is indices along axis==0
# second element of tuple is indices along axis==1

# Now let's get values at these indices:
>>> img_RGB[np.nonzero(img_RGB[:,:,2] != img_RGB[:,:,1])]
#        R    G    B
array([[254, 254, 255],
       [252, 252, 254],
       [251, 251, 253],
       ...,
       [144, 144, 142],
       [149, 149, 147],
       [133, 133, 131]], dtype=uint8)
# As can be seen, values in `G` and `B` are different in these, essentially `B`.
# Let's check for the first index, `G` is:
>>> img_RGB[16, 83, 1]
254
# And `B` is:
>>> img_RGB[16, 83, 1]
255
```

So printing an image array of shape `(1351, 1982)` is not a good idea to check for differences.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood as to why when doing `print(img_RGB[:,:,2])` and `print(img_RGB[:,:,1])` I obtain the same result. But, just to clarify, if I require to print only the blue channel as I am trying to do here, assuming the image has different values across the channels how would I know which to use whether `'1'` or `'2'`? Or is that dependent on the result I require?

Comment: `OpenCV` reads images in `BGR` by default, so without any conversion, you would need to access `img_RGB[:,:,0]` to get Blue, because `BGR -> Blue Green Red -> 0 1 2`. And as you have converted to `RGB`, you access `2`, to get Blue, `RGB -> 0 1 2`